# Set column names based on other/previous column names, probably using apply() or a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, apply

I have a large dataset where every 5 columns corresponds to measurements of 1 artery, but only the first of the five columns is named. An example:

```
df <- structure(list("agatston", "area", "volume", "density", "mass", 
                     "agatston", "area", "volume", "density", "mass", "agatston", 
                     "area", "volume", "density", "mass"), 
                .Names = c("Artery_1", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Artery_2", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Artery_3", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which looks like this:

```
df

# A tibble: 1 x 15
  Artery_1 ``    ``     ``      ``    Artery_2 ``    ``     ``      ``    Artery_3 ``    ``     ``      ``   
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
1 agatston area  volume density mass  agatston area  volume density mass  agatston area  volume density mass
```

I am trying to use a for loop or apply() to get the missing column names filled with the most recent non-missing column name. What I am trying to achieve looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 15
  Artery_1 Artery_1 Artery_1 Artery_1 Artery_1 Artery_2 Artery_2 Artery_2 Artery_2 Artery_2 Artery_3 Artery_3 Artery_3 Artery_3 Artery_3
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 agatston area     volume   density  mass     agatston area     volume   density  mass     agatston area     volume   density  mass
```

Any help?

Edit:
As a next step I would like to make the column non_unique by combining them with the name of the row below it, leading to the following output:

```
 # A tibble: 1 x 15
  Artery_1_agatson Artery_1_area Artery_1_volume Artery_1_density Artery_1_mass Artery_2_agatson Artery_2_area Artery_2_volume
  <chr>            <chr>         <chr>           <chr>            <chr>         <chr>            <chr>         <chr>          
1 agatston         area          volume          density          mass          agatston         area          volume         
# ... with 7 more variables: Artery_2_density <chr>, Artery_2_mass <chr>, Artery_3_agatson <chr>, Artery_3_area <chr>,
#   Artery_3_volume <chr>, Artery_3_density <chr>, Artery_3_mass <chr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zoo::na.locf` to replace the `NA` values.

````
names(df) <- zoo::na.locf(names(df))
names(df)

# [1] "Artery_1" "Artery_1" "Artery_1" "Artery_1" "Artery_1" "Artery_2"
# [7] "Artery_2" "Artery_2" "Artery_2" "Artery_2" "Artery_3" "Artery_3"
#[13] "Artery_3" "Artery_3" "Artery_3"```
````

However, it is not a good practice to have same column name so you may use `make.unique` to make the column names unique.

```
names(df) <- make.unique(zoo::na.locf(names(df)))
names(df)

# [1] "Artery_1"   "Artery_1.1" "Artery_1.2" "Artery_1.3" "Artery_1.4"
# [6] "Artery_2"   "Artery_2.1" "Artery_2.2" "Artery_2.3" "Artery_2.4"
#[11] "Artery_3"   "Artery_3.1" "Artery_3.2" "Artery_3.3" "Artery_3.4"
```

---

To combine the columns with the first row we can use

```
names(df) <- paste(zoo::na.locf(names(df)), df[1, ], sep = '_')
names(df)

# [1] "Artery_1_agatston" "Artery_1_area"     "Artery_1_volume"  
# [4] "Artery_1_density"  "Artery_1_mass"     "Artery_2_agatston"
# [7] "Artery_2_area"     "Artery_2_volume"   "Artery_2_density" 
#[10] "Artery_2_mass"     "Artery_3_agatston" "Artery_3_area"    
#[13] "Artery_3_volume"   "Artery_3_density"  "Artery_3_mass"
```

Then maybe drop the 1st row using `df <- df[-1, ]`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To adress the issue about non-unique column names: the next step would be to make them unique by combining them with the string in the row below. Would you also know how to achieve that?

Comment: I've added to my original question to make it more clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: the updated answer should help you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
names(df) <- paste(
  na.omit(names(df))[cumsum(!(is.na(names(df))))],
  df[1,,drop=TRUE],
  sep = "_"
)
```

OR dropping the first row:

```
clean_df <- setNames(
  df[-1,],
  paste(
    na.omit(names(df))[cumsum(!(is.na(names(df))))],
    df[1,,drop=TRUE],
    sep = "_"
  )
)
```